# Recovering files from kind of recognized USB drive

Tags: files, filesystems, usb-drive

I have got an USB drive which I can't mount anymore. 
using `ls -rtl /dev/disk/by-id` shows me the drive
`usb-verbatim -> ../../sdc`

Trying to mount it using `mount /dev/sdc /mnt/usb` fails "no medium found on /dev/sdc".

On Windows you can see, that there is a USB drive plugged in, but it's greyed out and you can't see the files, although it recognizes the manufacturer and states that it works fine.

Using software like photorec fails unsurprisingly, because it doesn't even recognize that there is a drive plugged in to /dev/sdc.

I tried to clone the drive using `dd if=/dev/sdc of=/some/other/drive` but again, it says "no medium on /dev/sdc".

Is there any way to rescue the data?

Comment: You do not mount drives, but mount partitions. the USB drive does have partitions? A few have just put data on a drive without partitions, but then it is not seen by most tools as partition table is first thing the tools read.

Comment: There has been a partition, but it's gone. Is there any tool that can read the drive anyway?

Comment: You mentioned photorec, did you try testdisk?